# Can someone help me interpret these poster requirement for a conference? Phrases like 'bleed', 'please outline all fonts'

Tags: posters

The requirements are in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFRkE.png).

> Final Size : 24" x 32" (yellow)
>   Artwork Safe area: green
>   Bleed: 24.25" x 32.25" (pink)
>
> Save final print ready file as PDF-x1a with crop and bleed
>   Please outline all fonts
>   Color mode: CMYK
>   all color must be CMYK build
>   no spot color, no pantone
>
> Any images should be at least 150 dpi
>   ideal 300 dpi for print quality

I am not sure what they mean by 'bleed', and also what they mean by 'Save Final Print Ready File as pdf-x 1 a with crops and bleed' ? I am also not sure what they mean by 'please outline all fonts'.

I googled the color mode, and it seems like something a print shop would know about, as well as the dpi requirements.

Comment: Depending upon how important this project is, you *might* consider hiring someone who understands this stuff. Much like fixing your car.. it may be possible to do yourself, but at times, to get things done correctly, you need a professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bleed" is essentially extra space so that printers have some margin for error. For more info [read this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/129/23061)

PDF-X1a is a PDF format. You can read more [on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf-x1a&oq=pdf-x1a&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.1940j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

By outline all fonts, they mean converting the fonts you use to paths (with outlines) so that they don't have to have the font file loaded on their computer.

Color mode is the type of color that is being used in the file. You can just change the mode in your image editor.

DPI stands for "dots per inch" and has to do with the quality of images. It's pretty easy to figure out for images in most software. In Windows you can right click an image and click Properties > Details to see it.